# uWSGI async functions don't know about Django's logging settings

Tags: python, django, logging, uwsgi

We're using uWSGI to serve our Django application. We also utilize uWSGI's mules and spooler system for running jobs at regular times and for performing some tasks asynchronously, out of the request/response cycle.

The part of the uWSGI which handles HTTP requests use [Django logging configuration](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/logging/#configuring-logging) just fine. However, when using uWSGI's `cron` and `mulefunc` features, often the logger won't be configured at all -- you'll call log.error() and the exception just disappears. We have discovered a bizarre workaround which I explain below.

Here are our logging settings, in `settings.py`. StreamHandler by default routes to stderr, so we should see any logs of level DEBUG and higher routed to stderr.

```
LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': True,
    'formatters': {
        'verbose': {
            'format': '%(levelname)s %(asctime)s %(module)s %(process)d %(thread)d %(message)s'
        },
    },
    'handlers': {
        'console': {
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
            'formatter': 'verbose'
        }
    },
    'loggers': {
        '': {
            'handlers': ['console'],
            'level': 'NOTSET',
        }
    }
}
```

Here's an example of what won't work:

```
from uwsgidecorators import mulefunc

log = logging.getLogger(__name__)

@timer(10, target="mule")
def test_mule_logging(signum):
    log.error("You'll never see this message")
```

However, there is a really strange workaround. If you import Django's settings, AND access a key on it, then the logger will magically work. For example:

```
from django.conf import settings
getattr(settings, "doesntmatter", None)

from uwsgidecorators import timer
import logging

log = logging.getLogger(__name__)

@timer(10, target="mule")
def test_mule_logging(signum):
    log.error("I WILL see this log!")
```

This seems like a horrible workaround though.

Answer (score 0):

I think the behaviour you describe makes sense.

In a regular worker, uwsgi loads a WSGI app that makes django load the settings, and as part of that configure the global Python logging system.  Library code that is run by the django app and contains logging statement ends up being handled by the logging config (without having to know that django exists or configured the logging system).

In a mule, uwsgi only runs the code that you give it, not the wsgi module/script defined for regular workers, so nothing is configuring the logging system.  The mules are still running within the same environment (uid, gid, chdir, virtualenv, pythonpath, env vars like DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE), so calling `django.setup()` (or `django.configure_settings`) will import your settings and configure the global logging system (global to the Python process that is the mule worker), fixing your logging calls.

Last piece of the puzzle: the `django.conf.settings` module is a special lazy object so that it can be imported by various modules before django has finished configuring itself, and defers really loading the settings until something tries to access a module attribute.  This behaviour can be obtained more explicitly in modern Django versions with `django.setup()`.